# parse and conditional push triggers for aggregated data

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are planning to use `parse.com` to send out push messages when certain events have been reached. For example I want parse to automatically send out a pre-defined push message when the user has logged in ten times. I don't want to take care of this in the application itself, rather I want to use the login-event which is sent to `parse.com` and set a conditional function for each user when this count has reached 10. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately certain events on Parse cloud cannot be tracked and a user log in is one of them, so in these cases you have to end up with a client/cloud hybrid solution to achieve what you want.

Please read the official [Parse documentation and guides](https://www.parse.com/docs). All the information on how to implement Push notifications or how to run your code on Parse Cloud is clearly explained in there.